# Web2Case / Email2Case - Image attachments feature?

Tags: web2case

Being the only admin in my company, it's my responsibility in my org to implement cases for our tech ticket process. Our products are highly technical and detailed so many questions come up that require photos from the customer to be sent it via email or through our Help Ticket form on our website.
I'm having a difficult time finding any service (that's not extremely over-priced)which allows image upload from web form to case, and will also associate the attachment to the case automatically with the form values.

I can't find anything similar in regards to the email to case feature either. Is this not even an option with standard UI, and if not is there any VF standard or custom controllers or code of some sort available that I could reference?